# List of particular events on particular items which took place after other events

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table similar to the following:

```
+--------+----------+--------+--------+
| itemID | actionID |  date  | userID |
+--------+----------+--------+--------+
|      3 | a        | 20-Apr | alice  |
|      4 | a        | 1-Jun  | bob    |
|      1 | b        | 2-Jun  | sam    |
|      5 | c        | 28-May | sally  |
|      4 | c        | 9-Apr  | sally  |
|      3 | b        | 24-Apr | bob    |
|      6 | b        | 29-Apr | bob    |
|      7 | a        | 15-May | alice  |
+--------+----------+--------+--------+
```

The scenario is like this:

I need to know whether `UserID X` has taken `actionID b` on `itemID Y` **after** the last time any user has taken `actionID a` on that `itemId Y`.

In the non-abstract, this is for a password manager.

Some user takes modifies a password `actionID a` on  `itemId Y` at `date Z`, and I need to know whether another user `userID A` has viewed `actionId b` after the modify `date Z`.

Also, if a user modifies a password, I need to assume they also are viewing the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from myTable t1
where userId = X and actionId = b and itemId = y
and t1.date > (select max(date) from myTable t2 where actionId = a and itemId = Y)
```

You may want to handle the case when no one has done action a on item Y yet.  Right now it will return nothing if no one has done that action yet.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.  Sorry I don't have enough rep to upvote you yet.

Comment: @user38858 It's fine.  I hope it works.  LEt me know if there is an issue with it.  If not, you can accept the answer for others to find.